# Take odd one out from a list when comparing with a filtered column using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have an excel as shown below:

[Input File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmKEo.png)

Now I want to filter fruits first from "Items" column and check which one in list of "list" column is not present in the list. For example: here "grapes" is not present in "Name" column. So I want grapes as output in next column as shown below.

[Expected Output Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipx7G.png)

The same is to be done for many by filtering each items one by one as I have many items.

Please suggest or give some hints so that i can start this code.

Comment: Cannot see your file and picture. You can get a preview of them during edit.

Comment: I can see the file and picture when clicking on underlined texts for ex : Input file and Expected Output Shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am naming the excel as Book1

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx")

frame_list_as_String = frame.list.tolist()
frame_list = [x.split(',') for x in frame_list_as_String]
frame_Name = frame.Name.tolist()
frame_col3=[]
for item in frame_list :
    frame_col3.append(list(set(items)-set(frame_Name)))

frame["col3"]=frame_col3

frame.to_excel("df.xlsx", index = False)
```